# Escape all double quotes inside a single quoted string with Regex

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, quotes, substitution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression to escape double quotes inside single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036341/regular-expression-to-escape-double-quotes-inside-single-quotes)

I need a regex (no other language!!, best would be perl syntax REGEX or PCRE syntax REGEX) to replace all double quotes `"` with a `\"` that are inside a single quoted string. This is an example string (part of a file):

```
var baseUrl = $("#baseurl").html();
var head = '<div id="finishingDiv" style="background-image:url({baseUrl}css/userAd/images/out_main.jpg); background-repeat: repeat-y; ">'+
'<div id="buttonbar" style="width:810px; text-align:right">';
```

(Be aware: They dont have to be paired "someValueBetween" so its possible that there are uneven numbers of double quotes in one single quoted string.)

This should be the end result for the last line above:

```
'<div id=\"buttonbar\" style=\"width:810px; text-align:right\">';
```

Thanks in advance

***Update:
To make it clear, i want a regular expression only, not a perl programm. The regular expression can be perl regex syntax or PHP PCRE syntax (which is a very close syntax to the perl regex syntax from what i understand). Goal is that you can run the regex in IDES in the search and replace menus that support regex's (like Eclipse and PhpEd f.e )!!

In other words, i want a regex that i will put in the search IDE field that gives me exactly all unescaped `"` in the single quoted string as a result. In the replace field of eclipse i can then just put `\$1` to escape them.

They should work in Regexbuddy or regex coach please so i can test them.

At least that is the plan :)

---

Comment: The regex is easier than the slashing of the regex strings -- are you looking for a javascript function that will slash "s?

Comment: no, im looking particularly for a regex and not a javascript, php, or perl function. It should be a simple regex that retrieves all not properly escaped "s in a single quoted string to replace them (maybe a $1 or something) with \"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked for Perl (or PCRE) and nothing else.

Ok.

If you just want to escape unescaped double quotes no matter where you find them, do this:

```
  s{
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{1} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{3} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{5} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{7} )
      (?= " )
  }{\\}xg;
```

If you want to escape unescaped double quotes between unescaped single quotes, and you only have one pair of such single quotes, do this:

```
1 while s{

  (?(DEFINE)

    (?<unescaped>
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{1} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{3} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{5} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{7} )
    )

    (?<single_quote> (?&unescaped) ' )
    (?<double_quote> (?&unescaped) " )
    (?<unquoted>     [^'] *?          )

  )

  (?<HEAD>
    (?&single_quote)
    (?&unquoted)
  )

  (?<TAIL>
    (?&double_quote)
    (?&unquoted)
    (?&single_quote)

  )

}<$+{HEAD}\\$+{TAIL}>xg;
```

But if you may have multiple sets of paired unescaped single quotes per line, and you only want to escape the unescaped double quotes that fall between those unescaped single quotes, then do this:

```
sub escape_quote {
  my $_ = shift;
  s{
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{1} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{3} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{5} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{7} )
      (?= " )
  }{\\}xg;

  return $_;
}

s{

  (?(DEFINE)

    (?<unescaped>
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{1} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{3} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{5} )
      (?<! (?<! \\ ) \\{7} )
    )

    (?<single_quote> (?&unescaped) ' )
    (?<unquoted>     [^'] *?          )

  )

  (?<HEAD> (?&single_quote) )
  (?<TARGET> (?&unquoted) )
  (?<TAIL> (?&single_quote) )

}{
               $+{HEAD}    .
  escape_quote($+{TARGET}) .
               $+{TAIL}

}xeg;
```

Note that this all presupposed you have no legitimate paired  unescaped double quotes containing unescaped single quotes.  Even something like this will throw you off:

```
my $cute = q(') . "stuff" . q(');
```

Probably, though, you want to use a proper parsing module.

Please pay no attention to all the garish and deceitfully incorrect SO coloring.  For some reason, it doesn't seem to be able to parse Perl as well as perl does.   Can't imagine why. ☺

Comment: Looks impressive man!!!  Is there a chance to run this in regexbuddy or regex coach and especially run this in eclipse as a search replace regex?  (Are you working for Perl?)

Comment: @Tschef: [Wikipedia on tchrist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Christiansen)

Comment: Ok, you got your own Wikipedia entry. Impressive i must say. I bow in front of you :)
Any help in the eclipse search and replace section for this regex? I cant force everybody in the team to install perl unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

According to your edit, you want a generic regex to be used in the search-and-replace feature of an unspecified IDE or text editor.  It's not that simple.  I'm sure you're aware that different languages (Perl, Java, Python, etc.) tend to have their own regex flavors, with different feature sets and syntactic quirks.  The situation among editors and IDE's is even worse.

**UPDATE:** Since I wrote this, Visual Studio has switched to using the .NET flavor, and Notepad++ has adopted the Boost library.  The regex below will now work in all the editors/IDE's I mentioned except Visual Studio. (.NET doesn't support possessive quantifiers, but it does have atomic groups, which can be used to the same effect.)

JEdit and IntelliJ IDEA, being written in Java, use Java's regex flavor, which is pretty good.  But Visual Studio does **not** use the excellent .NET flavor; instead it uses a legacy flavor with an eclectic feature set and bizarre syntax.  TextMate, the Mac editor that Apple devs rave about, uses the feature-rich Oniguruma flavor, but Notepad++ (a free Windows editor which also gets a lot of good press) use a flavor with an extremely limited feature set--it doesn't even support alternation!

So even relatively simple tasks can be difficult or impossible depending on the editor you're using, but what you're trying to do is pretty tricky.  Here's the simplest regex I've come up with for it:

**search:** `\G((?:(?:\A|')[^']*+')?+[^'"]*+)"([^'"]*+)`

**replace:** `$1\\"$2`

(This assumes every apostrophe is used as a quote; that none of them need to be ignored because they're in comments, double-quoted strings, or whatever; that there are no escaped quotes (single or double) already in the text; and the list goes on.)

The `\G` (the *end-of-previous-match* anchor) is essential, but that's a feature that isn't supported even by some of the more popular regex flavors, like JavaScript and Python.  Possessive quantifiers (`*+`, `?+`) keep the regex from bogging down when no match is possible; they're available in PCRE, Oniguruma, Perl 5.10+, and Java.  .NET doesn't have them, but it does have the somewhat clumsier alternative, atomic groups.

I suggest you forget about the generic-regex approach and standardize on a tool set that has the capabilities you need.  For general purposes, I don't think anything beats the JGSoft family of tools: EditPad Pro, PowerGrep, and RegexBuddy.  In both features and performance, the JGSoft regex flavor is as good as anything out there; all it lacks are the recursive-matching and embedded-code features.

**p.s.** I see you mentioned Eclipse in a comment; I don't have it installed, but I expect it uses Java's regex flavor (or possibly the ICU flavor, whose syntax is virtually identical to Java's), so the regex above should work in it.

Comment: That comes close actually but with the \G it does not really work. It has the \G option in the regex syntax but it does not work with it! 
If i leave it out if messes up the regex i guess because what it does is escape all " no matter where or if they are in single quotes.
Is there a chance to make this statement work line by line somehow. That would be enough i guess.

Comment: This is in Eclipse?  It might be that you have to escape things differently.  Here's how it looks in (correctly working) Java code: `replaceAll("\\G((?:(?:\\A|')[^']*+')?+[^'\"]*+)\"([^'\"]*+)", "$1\\\\\"$2")`  I wouldn't expect an editor's search widget to require all that escaping, but maybe...

Comment: The syntax was fine, but with the \G in front it does not find anythng surprisingly. According to the eclipse regex syntax it has support for \G and \A. Also the rest is ok, and it is only with one slash always.
Can you tell me what exactly the \G and \A do, the rest is ok to understand, though i would have never got it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as there's only one single-quoted string per line (as in your example), this should work (sed syntax):

```
s|'\([^'"]*\)"\([^']*\)'|'\1\"\2'|g
```

Comment: @Downvoter: I think that it's the best solution that works with one regexp.

Comment: That's an invalid Perl regex, or at least an incorrect and illadvised one.  First, you should not put `\1` and such in the RHS of a substitution.  Second, you should not escape parens in the LHS if you expect to populate a capture group. Third, there are many scenarios you don't account for.

Comment: Doesnt work in RegexBuddy with Perl syntax at all unfortunately. I dont understand how the capturing groups should work with a \ in front of them. I hope to understand it though

Comment: @Tschef: At least with GNU sed 4.2.1, you have to escape the brackets to give them their special meaning.